# Create multi-dimension array using javascript

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

We have developed one application in HTML and we want to define multi-dimension array. For example we have 5 records then we want to create array shown below using java script. Any one have sample code to generate the array.

```
0       1       2       3       4       5
```

0   0:00    0:12    0:06    0:00    0:06    0:06
1   0:11    0:00    0:12    0:11    0:15    0:13
2   0:05    0:12    0:00    0:05    0:06    0:00
3   0:00    0:12    0:06    0:00    0:06    0:06
4   0:06    0:15    0:05    0:06    0:00    0:05
5   0:05    0:12    0:00    0:05    0:06    0:00

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple approach.

```
var arr = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [44, 34, 0],
  [9, 2, 4]
];
```

console.log(arr[2][1]) //outputs 2

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
    ["0:00", "0:12", "0:06", "0:00", "0:06", "0:06"],
    ["0:11", "0:00", "0:12", "0:11", "0:15", "0:13"], 
    ["0:05", "0:12", "0:00", "0:05", "0:06", "0:00"],
    ["0:00", "0:12", "0:06", "0:00", "0:06", "0:06"],
    ["0:06", "0:15", "0:05", "0:06", "0:00", "0:05"],
    ["0:05", "0:12", "0:00", "0:05", "0:06", "0:00"]
]
```

where `arr[2]` evaluates to `["0:05", "0:12", "0:00", "0:05", "0:06", "0:00"]`

or

```
var dict = {
    0: ["0:00", "0:12", "0:06", "0:00", "0:06", "0:06"],
    1: ["0:11", "0:00", "0:12", "0:11", "0:15", "0:13"], 
    2: ["0:05", "0:12", "0:00", "0:05", "0:06", "0:00"],
    3: ["0:00", "0:12", "0:06", "0:00", "0:06", "0:06"],
    4: ["0:06", "0:15", "0:05", "0:06", "0:00", "0:05"],
    5: ["0:05", "0:12", "0:00", "0:05", "0:06", "0:00"]
}
```

where `dict[2]` evaluates to `["0:05", "0:12", "0:00", "0:05", "0:06", "0:00"]`

Comment: thanks for your reply but we want to create matrix dynamically. may be it will be 100 * 100 matrix. In that case how we do it javascript.

Comment: How does your input look? Do you have a string that looks like "0 0:00 0:12 0:06 0:00 0:06 0:06 1 0:11 0:00 0:12 0:11 0:15 0:13 2 0:05 0:12 0:00 0:05 0:06 0:00 3 0:00 0:12 0:06 0:00 0:06 0:06 4 0:06 0:15 0:05 0:06 0:00 0:05 5 0:05 0:12 0:00 0:05 0:06 0:00" which you want to transform into a JavaScript array?